# how login and pay using webmoney automatically

Tags: php, automation, payment-gateway, php-curl, payment-processing

I am trying to create a script that tracks a payment link, which goes from the payment gateway site(with special invoice number example "https://paymaster.com/process/123-123-123")  to webmoney payment page,but the problem is how to following the redirection and logs into my webmoney account and makes the payment automatically ?
i'm trying to use curl but i get error stop in "Object Moved to HERE" and if i follow the new link i don't know how to login and complete the payment automatically
any idea please ?

```
$url = "https://merchant.web.money/lmi/payment.asp?lang=en-US";
$data2 = http_build_query(array( 
"LMI_PAYEE_PURSE"=>"my purse address",
"LMI_SHOP_ID"=>"the shop id",
"LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT"=>"100",
"LMI_PAYMENT_NO"=>"250515555",
"LMI_PAYMENT_DESC_BASE64"=>"description of good coded in BASE64",
"LMI_RESULT_URL"=>"result url ,where webmoney will send notification if payment complete",
"LMI_FAIL_URL"=>"here where webmoney will send notification if payment failed",
"LMI_FAIL_METHOD"=>"POST",
"LMI_SUCCESS_URL"=>"redirect me here if finished",
"LMI_SUCCESS_METHOD"=>"LINK",
"LMI_FAST_PHONENUMBER"=>"",
"LMI_PAYMENTFORM_SIGN"=>"FFA58DA58B00C8238FC229A28BE57421CDD44AE99773C98AA319AAA8258A1DFC",
));
$cookie = 'prevsave=1;MPR=22965;epz=1;prevparam=authtype_17;phone=my webmoney address;wm_ids=950438291137|c4e5f9c2884b42efa98321e409581540-a7fe77dcfd570a99344b731b1253ff18;_ga=GA1.2.1534257924.1595532585;wm_ids_2=[{"my WMID":"my WMID md5 coded"}];_pk_ses.4.730b=*;_pk_id.4.730b=d7c5cda075b20ddf.1594819506.63.1596577154.1596575396.;_pk_ref.4.730b=["","",1596575396,"the same in LMI_SUCCESS_URL"];';
$init = curl_init(); // initialize
curl_setopt($init,CURLOPT_URL,$url); // connect the server
curl_setopt($init,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); // return connection result
curl_setopt($init,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($init,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"cookie_file_from_my_device_because_i_think_it_stored_login_info");
curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$content = curl_setopt($init,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data2);
$output = curl_exec($init); // excute the curl
$getinfo = curl_getinfo($init);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Post your code. We can't help with what we can't see or don't know how it's not working for you,.

Comment: sorry but i was think my code wasn't help anymore...i was edited my post and added code